# ¿Cómo puedo agregar registros con poblamiento masivo? [SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, base-de-datos

Quisiera saber como es que puedo agregar datos a diferentes tablas que no sea utilizando INSERT... sino utilizando algo llamado "poblamiento masivo", lo que hace referencia a agregar información almacenada en un script sql por separado.

Tengo todas mis tablas hechas, solo me falta insertar los datos como se me indica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto número 5 indica lo que necesito. 
En sencillas palabras es agregar datos almacenados en un script aparte sin realizar INSERT.

Comment: Como son pocos registros no creo que te estén pidiendo gran cosa. Genera los insert para cada tabla en fichero de texto  y pegalos en la consola de mysql. No te están pidiendo un script de benchmark. O si?

Comment: oracle? mysql? son dos bases distintas.. cual estas usando?

Answer (score 0):

Se debe importar los datos desde un texto plano ".txt", estos deben ser ordenados y separado por una "," (puede varias según la configuración que se tenga como separador de datos).

ejemplo: en la tabla ciudad el archivo .txt con datos sería algo como lo siguiente...

1,Santiago

2,Chiloe

3,Quillota

4,Concepcion

5,Cartagena